# How to change the child state component from parent in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a Count down timer component
and I have a Button near this component

and I want when users click on this button, resets the timer

and for doing this I should change the child state

I found the solution for changing parent state from the child
but I don't find the solution to this

can it be solved with ref ??
( my timer component is a functional component )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React ref forwarding is the solution:
This blog will describe more: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-refs-both-class-and-functional-components-76b7bce487b8

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class ChildClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timer: 100
    };
    this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
  }
  resetTimer() {
    this.setState({
      timer: 0
    });
  }
  render() {
    let { timer } = this.state;
    return <span>{timer}</span>;
  }
}

const ChildFunction = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(100);
  const resetTimer = () => {
    setTimer(0);
  };
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, ()=>({
    resetTimer
  }));
  return <span>{timer}</span>;
});

export default function App() {
  let childClassRef = React.createRef(null);
  let childFuncRef = React.createRef(null);
  const resetClassTimer = () => {
    childClassRef.current.resetTimer();
  };
  const resetFuncTimer = () => {
    childFuncRef.current.resetTimer();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildClass ref={childClassRef} />
      <button onClick={resetClassTimer}>Reset</button>
      <br/>
      <ChildFunction ref={childFuncRef} />
      <button onClick={resetFuncTimer}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have added both ref forwarding with class components and functional components.
It is same with both React.js and React native.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to pass you props in child to get parent updated state

```
  cont Parent = (props) =>{

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(100)

   cont resetTimer = () => {
      setTimer(0)
   }
   render(){
        return <span>{timer}</span>
        <Child timer={timer}>
      }
}
```

In Child

```
cont Child = (props) =>{
      const timer= props.timer;
      render(){
        return <span>I am child with time {timer}</span>
      }
  }
```

Comment: timer state changes in child component..... because this is a reusable component

Answer (score 0):

One way is, If you want to change parent state from child component then you should call parent function from child component through props

```
cont Child = (props) =>{
      render(){
        return (<span>I am child with time {props.timer}</span>
        <Button onClick = {props.resetTimer}></Button>
        )
      }
  }

cont Parent = (props) =>{

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(100)

   cont resetTimer = () => {
      setTimer(0)
   }
   render(){
        return <span>{timer}</span>
        <Child timer={timer} setTimer={setTimer}>
      }
}
```